How can I increase number of qubits by increasing RAM/GPU?
I am using Qiskit, where if I go beyond 32 qubits, the output does not get counted.
The code is not supported by the stabilizer back-end. I want to use up to 100+ qubits for my task. I got RAM 42 GB and GPU RAM 16 GB, which I think can accommodate more qubits. Also, I'm using precision 'single' to use less memory space.
Is there any method I can use to increase the number of qubits by increasing RAM?

$2^{32}$ is around 4GB, so I don't think you can store a 100+ qubit system without exploring some structure within your state. With the MPS simulator you can get up to 100 qubits.

Thankyou, using the matrix product state increased the number of qubits for the same ram. Currently, I'm able to use about 60+ qubits. What if I need even more, is there any way?
